# How to add trusted certificates to openssl on LFS

Tags: wget, openssl, ssl, certificates

I have an LFS system (11.0) with openssl. Whenever I use wget, I get an error that the certificate is not trusted. Where do I get and put trusted certificates?

Comment: Not enough info. Check whether certs are in `/etc/ssl/certs`. Extract the root cert or the self-signed for the remote system and install it into `/usr/share/pki/trust/anchors` or where ever your system stores user root certs and run `update-ca-certificates`, or your o/s's equivelent. Alternatively, run `wget --no-check-certificate` to just ignore the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is described [in the LFS book](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.1/postlfs/cacerts.html)

- Put your certificate into `/etc/ssl/local/your_cert.pem`. Note: The extension must be `*.pem`.
- Run `make-ca -g --force`